# jQuery get width of a clicked element store in variable

Tags: jquery, arrays, click, width

I have some basic markup:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
    <div class=".content"></div>
</div>
```

I would like to get the width of .content each time it is clicked and store it in an array. I have the following jQuery code:

```
var listWidth = [];
    $('.content').click(function(){
        listWidth.push($(this).width());
    });

    console.log(listWidth);
```

This is not passing the width value to the array. It does work when I use alert like this:

```
var listWidth = [];
    $('.content').click(function(){
        alert($(this).width());
    });

    console.log(listWidth);
```

Can anyone help me out? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you log the array before the click functions have been triggered

Answer (score 4):

Call `console.log` from within the click event.

```
var listWidth = [];
$('.content').click(function(){
    listWidth.push($(this).width());
    console.log(listWidth);
});
```

You are logging the array when it's empty, before the click event pushes anything into the array.